# Java GUI programming: Setting the Fore/Background

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, colors, jframe

I'm just getting into GUI programming, slowly learning.

However I'm having a problem right of the bat. I can't get the Fore/Background color to change in my window at all.

However when I add a label via JLabel and then use setFore/Back, they change colors just fine. Just not the whole window.

I thought .setForeground and .setBackground are supposed to change the color of the window?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MyWindow {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
         Runnable init = new Runnable()
         {
             public void run()
             {

                    JFrame myWindow = new JFrame("Hola!");
                    myWindow.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
                    myWindow.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                    myWindow.setSize(400, 300);

                    myWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    myWindow.setLayout(null);

                    myWindow.setVisible(true);

             }

         };
         SwingUtilities.invokeLater(init);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 9):

First of all, **do not use a null layout**. Let the layout manager do its job. Second of all, you need to **set the background of the content pane** of the `JFrame` instance, as such

```
myWindow.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
```

See also:

- [Using Top-Level Containers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html)

Comment: Here is an explanation of the various swing layers which may help explain this behavior: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html

Answer (score 3):

you cannot color a frame. However you can color the ContentPane inside.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

    public class MyWindow {

        public static void main(String args[])
        {
             Runnable init = new Runnable()
             {
                 public void run()
                 {

                        JFrame myWindow = new JFrame("Hola!");

    myWindow.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

                        myWindow.setSize(400, 300);

                        myWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                        myWindow.setLayout(null);

                        myWindow.setVisible(true);

                 }

             };
             SwingUtilities.invokeLater(init);
        }  
    }
```

this should fix your problem...

Answer (score -1):

tangina naman ang bobo naman neto, pokegooo

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

```
public class MyWindow {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
         Runnable init = new Runnable()
         {
             public void run()
             {

                    JFrame myWindow = new JFrame("Hola!");

myWindow.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

                    myWindow.setSize(400, 300);

                    myWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    myWindow.setLayout(null);

                    myWindow.setVisible(true);

             }

         };
         SwingUtilities.invokeLater(init);
    }  
}
```

// tanga amputa aral ka muna dudong 
// pakangkang